# How to use parameter in the Cypher statement for variable length pattern matching?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In our project , PEPOLEs are connected by KNOWS relationships. We need to query one’s friends in depth n which n is a parameter inputed by user.We use Spring Data Neo4j to implement it.

```
public interface PeopleRepository extends GraphRepository<People>
{
    @Query("MATCH (startnode{name:{name}})-[:KNOWS*1..{depth}]-(remote_friend) RETURN remote_friend.name");

    List<People> getFriendsInDepth(@Param("name") String name, @Param("depth") Integer depth);
}
```

The above codes won’t work. But if I replace {depth} parameter with a fixed Integer value as follows:

```
@Query("MATCH (startnode{name:{name}})-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(remote_friend) RETURN remote_friend.name");

List<People> getFriendsInDepth(@Param("name") String name, @Param("depth") Integer depth);
```

it works. I know the problem is caused by the depth parameter. But I have tried a lot of methods to replace {depth}, for example: toInt({depth}), it still won’t work. Is there anyone know how to use the parameter in  the Cypher statement for variable length pattern matching?

Answer (score 2):

Cypher does not allow you to parameterize the depth of a relationship, hence @Query won't support it either.

If you use Spring Data Neo4j 4, then perhaps you can translate your `@Query` to a set of `org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.Filter`.

Then you can use the `Session.loadAll` methods which accept `Filters` as well as a depth. 
[MusicIntegrationTest](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/integration/music/MusicIntegrationTest.java) contains a couple of Filter examples.